# Как отсортировать массив PHP по названию ссылки

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, внутри него ссылки:

```
$array = array(
"<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/a/texas.html'>Texas</a>",
"<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/idaho.html'>Idaho</a>",
"<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/washington.html'>Washington</a>",
"<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/seattle.html'>Seatle</a>",
 );
```

Просто с помощью sort() естественно не получается, так как он сортирует по тексту всей ссылки, а не по ее названию.

Comment: Написать собственную функцию сравнения строк http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/a/texas.html'>Texas</a>",
    "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/idaho.html'>Idaho</a>",
    "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/washington.html'>Washington</a>",
    "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/seattle.html'>Seatle</a>",
);
```

Можно так:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/i', '$1', $a);
    $b = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/i', '$1', $b);
    return $a > $b;
});
```

Аналогично без регулярок:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a = strip_tags($a);
    $b = strip_tags($b);
    return $a > $b;
});
```

Вывод:

```
var_dump($array);
```

---

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/idaho.html'>Idaho</a>"
  [1]=>
  string(59) "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/seattle.html'>Seatle</a>"
  [2]=>
  string(56) "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/a/texas.html'>Texas</a>"
  [3]=>
  string(66) "<a href='https://site.ru/catalog/b/washington.html'>Washington</a>"
}
```